# window background image not showing on iphone Titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

i have created tab group with single tab and window for tab , i have set background image for tab window, image is showing properly on android but in iPhone i cant see any image any solution to this problem?

```
var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup({
    navBarHidden: true,
    layout: 'vertical'
});
Ti.UI.Clipboard.setText('');
var db = require('dbhelper');
db.callDb();
var windowTitle = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    color: '#fff',
    text: 'IEMR LITE'
});
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
});
if (Ti.Platform.name === 'iPhone OS') {
    win1.titleControl = windowTitle;
    win1.barImage = 'images/actionbar3.png';
    win1.hideTabBar();
} else {}
win1.backgroundImage = 'images/default_portrait.png';
```

Comment: do you have any example code?

Comment: var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup({
 navBarHidden : true,
 layout : 'vertical'
});
Ti.UI.Clipboard.setText('');


var db = require('dbhelper');
db.callDb();

var windowTitle = Ti.UI.createLabel({
 color : '#fff',
 text : 'IEMR LITE'
});

var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
 backgroundColor : '#fff'
});

if (Ti.Platform.name === 'iPhone OS') {
 win1.titleControl = windowTitle; 
 win1.barImage = 'images/actionbar3.png';
 win1.hideTabBar();
} else {

}

win1.backgroundImage = 'images/default_portrait.png';

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code and its works for me. also make sure you are providing correct image path.

```
var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup({ 
        navBarHidden : true, 
        layout : 'vertical' 
    }); 
    Ti.UI.Clipboard.setText(''); 
    //var db = require('dbhelper'); 
    //db.callDb(); 
    var windowTitle = Ti.UI.createLabel({ 
        color : '#fff', 
        text : 'IEMR LITE' 
    }); 
    var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({ 
        backgroundColor : '#fff' 
    }); 
    if (Ti.Platform.name === 'iPhone OS') { 
        win1.titleControl = windowTitle;
        win1.barImage = '1.png'; 
        win1.hideTabBar(); 
        } else { } 
    win1.backgroundImage = '2.png';
    var tab1 =Ti.UI.createTab({
        window : win1
    });
    tabGroup.addTab(tab1);
    tabGroup.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your `build` folder and building for iPhone again. Sometimes after adding an image (or other binary resource), it doesn't get linked to the underlying built project properly until you do a clean build.